# Wireless connection setting in ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386 (Offline )

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I just installed ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386, but it didn't detect my wireless card (BCM4313). I don't have internet connection in ubuntu, but i have wireless connection in Window 7 environment.

I googled about it, and I found this solution for offline operation:

1. I believe the package you need is [linux-firmware-nonfree](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/all/linux-firmware-nonfree/download).
2. Please download the package, transfer it on a USB stick or similar to the desktop of the Xubuntu machine.
3. Open terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i Desktop/linux*.deb  
   sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
   ```
4. You should be all set.

   - I have followed the above instructions but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -rv wl
sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac
```

if there are any errors please continue with the commands then reboot.